# Beginner Java Code Issues

Tags: java

```
public class Printing {

public static void printStars(int amount) {
    int i = 1;
    while (i<amount) {
        System.out.print("*");
        i++;
    if (i==amount) {
           System.out.println("*");

       }
    }   

}



public static void printTriangle(int size) {
    int c = 1;
    while (c<=size) {
        printStars(c);
        c++;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {


    printStars(3);
    System.out.println("\n---");
    printSquare(4);
    System.out.println("\n---");
    printRectangle(5, 6);
    System.out.println("\n---");
    printTriangle(3);
    System.out.println("\n---");
}
```

}

I'm currently following an online course on learning Java and in this assignment, printTriangle(3) should print 3 rows of stars, first row with 1 star, second row with 2 stars, third row with 3 stars.

I can't figure out why it only prints 2 rows of stars, first row with 2 stars and second row with 3 stars.

I edited out the parts where I defined methods printSquare and printRectangle because I figured they weren't important.

The program I'm using to code is Netbeans with TMC 1.1.7

Comment: One thing that's important to learn is how to test your code.  Try adding `printStars(1);` to the main method and then try to figure out the result.

Comment: The first loop in `printTriangle()` is calling `printStars(1);`, try that by itself as @markspace mentioned.

Comment: `Stream.generate(() -> "*").limit(amount).forEach(System.out::print); System.out.println();`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch he seems to be a beginner so definitely he won't know streams and other features of java :)

Comment: Can you upvote some answer/answer's which were useful

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `if loop` and change the condition in the `while loop` to `i<=amount`. What's happening now in your while loop is, you are checking if `i` is less than `amount` `( i < amount )`. In the first iteration you will call printStars(1) so in this case `amount = 1` and `i = 1`. In the while loop the comparison becomes `1<1` which is `false`. The `if condition` `(i==amount)` is not even reached because the outer while loop itself broke, the method execution ends without printing 1 star as expected. If you change the while condition to `i<=amount` then the comparison is `1<=1` the condition is `true` so it will print 1 star.

```
public static void printStars(int amount) { 
    int i = 1; 
    while (i<=amount) { 
          System.out.print("*"); 
          i++; 
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe my code is simple, but I can show the same result with these piece of logic.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

   int i = 0; int o = 0;//initialize variables
   while (i<3)//first counter -- line by line
   {
        while (o<i)//second counter -- describes how many @ sign 
                                     //(or in your case, use asterisk (*))
                                     //should be printed on the same line
        {
          System.out.print("@"); 
          o++;
        }
        o=0;

     System.out.println("@");    
     i++;
   }
 }
```

The output looks like:

> @
>
> @@
>
> @@@

Hope it helps!

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

change your while loop to

```
 while (i<=amount) {
    if (i==amount) {
       System.out.println("*");

   }else{
    System.out.print("*");

    }
  i++;
}
```

in print stars method

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the `for` loop.

```
public static void printStars(int amount) {
  for (int i = 1; i <= amount; i++) {
    System.out.print("*");
  }
  System.out.println("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the count is equal to amount we need to change to new line so that next time you use your method it starts printing stars in the next line or you can change to always insert a new line when you go into the method the first time.

Change your method to this:-

```
public static void printStars(int amount) {
    int i = 1;
    while (i<=amount) {
        System.out.print("*");
        if (i==amount) {
           System.out.println("");

       }
       i++;
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I choose **nested** `for loop` to implement. The **inner loop** is to print row. **Outer loop** is to change line.

```
public static void printStars(int amount) { 

  for (int i = 1; i <= amount; i++) { 
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
       System.out.print("*"); //to print row
    } 
    System.out.println("");   //to change line
  }

}
```